# How to add boundaries to my camera without jittering?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a clash of clans style game in unity, and I'm new to unity and C# scripting so take it easy on me. So far I've written two scripts with the help of forums and YouTube. The first is a script called PerspectivePan and is attached to an empty object named perspectiveHolder in the hierarchy. The second script's called clampBounds and is attached to the main camera. The main camera is attached to perspectiveHolder via a variable named cam in the first script. The first script pans and zooms, the second sets up boundaries for the camera. Ive been able to keep the camera in bounds, but the camera jitters at the edges and allows you to go out go out of bounds up until you let go of the mouse button while panning. How can I stop panning at the edges while stopping the jittering?

```
public class PerspectivePan : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 touchStart;
    public Camera cam;
    public float groundZ = 0;
    public float zoomOutMin = 1;
    public float zoomOutMax = 8;
    private bool multiTouch = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            touchStart = GetWorldPosition(groundZ);
            multiTouch = false;
        }

        if (Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

            Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
            Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

            float prevMagnitude = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
            float currentMagnitude = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

            float difference = currentMagnitude - prevMagnitude;

            zoom(difference * 0.01f);

            multiTouch = true;
        }

        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && multiTouch == false)
        {
            Vector3 direction = touchStart - GetWorldPosition(groundZ);
            Camera.main.transform.position += direction;
        }

        zoom(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel"));

    }

    private Vector3 GetWorldPosition(float z)
    {
        Ray mousePos = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Plane ground = new Plane(Vector3.down, new Vector3(0, 0, z));
        float distance;
        ground.Raycast(mousePos, out distance);
        return mousePos.GetPoint(distance);
    }

    void zoom(float increment)
    {
        Camera.main.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(Camera.main.fieldOfView - increment*10, zoomOutMin, zoomOutMax);
    }
}
```

```
public class clampBounds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxX, minX, maxY, minY, maxZ, minZ;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minX, maxX), Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, minY, maxY), Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, minZ, maxZ));
    }
}
```

Comment: A suggestion: For example, define a bool flag for the left edge. When value is clamped, set this flag as true. Do not scroll to left when cursor is on the left edge because flag is true. If user scrolls right, then set the flag as false.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Clamp()` method to your clampBounds class and then call `GetComponent<clampBounds>().Clamp()` to the end of your PerspectivePan `Update()` method.

The PerspectivePan is probably updated AFTER the clampBounds, and thus, the adjustments that clampBounds makes are overridden and completely ignored whenever PerspectivePan updates the camera position